# Plotly: bar plot with color red<0, green>0, divided by groups

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Given a dataframe with 2 groups: (group1, group2), that have values > and < than 0:
plot:

- Bar plot
- x = x
- y = values, divided by group1, group2
- color = red if value<0, green if value>0
- legend shows group1, grou2 with different colors.

My current code however is not coloring as i would expect, and the legend is shown with the same color:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px 

df = pd.DataFrame( {
    "x" : [1,2,3],
    "group1" : [np.nan, 1, -0.5],
    "group2" : [np.nan, -0.2, 1],  
}).set_index("x")


df_ = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars = 'x')
fig = px.bar(df_, x='x', y='value', color='variable', barmode='group')
fig.update_traces(marker_color=['red' if val < 0 else 'green' for val in df_['value']], marker_line_color='black', marker_line_width=1.5)
fig.show()
```

OUT with indications of what i want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: sorry, plotly.express I edited

Comment: Legend colors doesn't mean anything if you choose to color bar individually as a function of x values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stick with `plotly.express`, I would add a column to your dataframe, e.g. `df_['positive']` with a boolean, and then color your plot by this variable.

It would look like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px 

df = pd.DataFrame( {
    "x" : [1,2,3],
    "group1" : [np.nan, 1, -0.5],
    "group2" : [np.nan, -0.2, 1],  
}).set_index("x")

df_ = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars = 'x')
df_['positive'] = (df_['value']>=0)

fig = px.bar(df_, x='x', y='value',barmode = 'group',
                color='positive',
                color_discrete_map={
                    True: 'green',
                    False: 'red'
                    }
)
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='black', marker_line_width=1.5)
fig.show('browser')
```

which yields the following :
[image]

### EDIT following comments

If you want to keep the colors AND the group distinction within `plotly.express`, one way could be to add patterns...

##### Solution 1 : Every combination has its legend entry

```py
df = pd.DataFrame( {
    "x" : [1,2,3],
    "group1" : [np.nan, 1, -0.5],
    "group2" : [np.nan, -0.2, 1],  
}).set_index("x")

df_ = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars = 'x')
positive = (df_['value']>=0)
df_['positive'] = positive
df_['sign'] = ['positive' if x else 'negative' for x in df_['positive']]
# Each compbination of color and patterns
fig = px.bar(df_, x='x', y='value',barmode = 'group',
                color='sign',
                color_discrete_map={
                    'positive': 'green',
                    'negative': 'red'
                    },
                pattern_shape="variable")
fig.update_layout(legend_title="Groups & Signs", bargap=0.5,bargroupgap=0.1)
fig.show('browser')
```

which outputs the following
[image]

##### Solution 2 : Legend only reflects patterns

```py
# Only patterns in legend
fig = px.bar(df_, x='x', y='value', color='variable',
                barmode='group',pattern_shape="variable")
fig.update_layout(legend_title="Groups", bargap=0.5,bargroupgap=0.1)
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace: trace.update(marker_color=np.where(df_.loc[df_['variable'].eq(trace.name), 'value'] < 0, 'red', 'green'))
)
fig.show('browser')
```

which outputs :
[image]
However I was not able to 'remove' the green color from the legend...

Comment: thanks, howver with this solution the legend doesn't reflect "group1, group2" maybe it isn't possible to have the legend stay as group1, group2, with separate colors for legend lables (any assigned color), whilst coloring the bars with a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Since this cannot be achieved with express, we use a graph object to draw a bar chart for each group. The logic for color determination by numerical values is changed for Group 1 and Group 2, changing the conditions for Group 1 and Group 2. The reason is that the legend will not be color-coded unless this is done.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px 
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame( {
    "x" : [1,2,3],
    "group1" : [np.nan, 1, -0.5],
    "group2" : [np.nan, -0.2, 1],  
}).set_index("x")

df_ = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars = 'x')

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_.query('variable =="group1"')['x'],
                     y=df_.query('variable =="group1"')['value'],
                     marker_color=['red' if val < 0 else 'green' for val in df_.query('variable =="group1"')['value']],
                     marker_line_color='black',
                     marker_line_width=1.5,
                     name='group1',
                     #legendgroup='group1'
                    )
             )

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_.query('variable =="group2"')['x'],
                     y=df_.query('variable =="group2"')['value'],
                     marker_color=['green' if val > 0 else 'red' for val in df_.query('variable =="group2"')['value']],
                     marker_line_color='black',
                     marker_line_width=1.5,
                     name='group2',
                     #legendgroup='group2'
                    )
             )
fig.update_layout(barmode='group', xaxis=dict(title_text='x'), yaxis=dict(title_text='value'))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to color bar according their `x` value (and not `variable` group), you have to update traces individually (or you have to draw graph objects manually):

```
fig = px.bar(df_, x='x', y='value', color='variable', barmode='group')
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace: trace.update(marker_color=np.where(df_.loc[df_['variable'].eq(trace.name), 'value'] < 0, 'red', 'green'))
)
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)  # Hide legend because there is no distinct group
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks, Is there a way to aslo show the legend? I would like the legend to show with 2 separate colors for group1, group2. (any colors will do), so that they are distinguishable.

Comment: It's not possible to do it automatically because you have only one attribute (marker_color) to control the colors of the group.